# Cask 'x2goclient' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':x11'

Tags: macos, homebrew

As title says, I'm getting the

```
Cask 'x2goclient' definition is invalid: invalid depends_on key: ':x11'
```

error while trying to upgrade x2goclient. The error also occurs when I try to uninstall x2goclient. Even `--force` option can't fix it.

I can delete the x2goclient from Application folder but how do I remove x2goclient from my homebrew list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casks are installed in `$(brew --prefix)/Caskroom` so you can force uninstall `x2goclient` by running this command:

```
rm -rf $(brew --prefix)/Caskroom/x2goclient
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks :)